# Create a time series that counts the 3 years before and 3 after each M&A operation for each bank in the dataset

Tags: r, time-series

I have a dataset with a series of variables. the dataset consists of the names of the banks, the variable t for years ranging from 2004 to 2020, a dummy variable (Operation) which has the value 1 if in a specific year there was an M&A operation and then an asset_tot variable  that contains total asset variable for each year for each bank.
I want to create a time series that counts the 3 years before and 3 after each M&A operation for each bank in the dataset, and then see how the asset_tot variables vary as a function of time with respect to these events(M&A). How can i do in R?
thank you for your time

I want to use this data as the dependent variable of my regression analysis

Comment: Please provide an example of your data. Your question is too vague as is to answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I want to see how the average of the total assets of the 3 years after the M&A event which is indicated with a dummy(Operation=1) changes compared to the average of the total assets of the three years before